# Python math going wrong

Tags: python, math

My code is supposed to take the input of the persons grades and print out the average from highest to lowest, but when I run it, it doesn't give me the correct average.

This is my code

```
import math

name1 = input("Student #1")
name2 = input("Student #2")
name3 = input("Student #3")
name4 = input("Student #4")
name5 = input("Student #5")
MidTermGrade1 = input("Student #1 Midterm Grade")
MidTermGrade2 = input("Student #2 Midterm Grade")
MidTermGrade3 = input("Student #3 Midterm Grade")
MidTermGrade4 = input("Student #4 Midterm Grade")
MidTermGrade5 = input("Student #5 Midterm Grade")
EndTermGrade1 = input("Student #1 Endterm Grade")
EndTermGrade2 = input("Student #2 Endterm Grade")
EndTermGrade3 = input("Student #3 Endterm Grade")
EndTermGrade4 = input("Student #4 Endterm Grade")
EndTermGrade5 = input("Student #5 Endterm Grade")
# Student grades represented as tuples (name, midterm, final)
student_grades = [
   (name1, MidTermGrade1, EndTermGrade1),
   (name2, MidTermGrade2, EndTermGrade2),
   (name3, MidTermGrade3, EndTermGrade3),
   (name4, MidTermGrade4, EndTermGrade4),
   (name5, MidTermGrade5, EndTermGrade5)
]
# Function to calculate the average grade for each student
def calculate_average(grades):
   return int(grades[1] + grades[2]) / 2
# Function to find the student with the highest average grade
def find_highest_average(grades_list):
   highest_avg = 0
   highest_avg_student = None
   for student in grades_list:
      avg_grade = calculate_average(student)
      if avg_grade > highest_avg:
         highest_avg = avg_grade
         highest_avg_student = student
   return highest_avg_student
# Function to sort students based on their average grades
def sort_students_by_average(grades_list):
   return sorted(grades_list, key=calculate_average, reverse=True)
# Main program
if __name__ == "__main__":
   # Display the original list of student grades
   print("Original Student Grades:")
   for student in student_grades:
      print(f"{student[0]}: Midterm - {student[1]}, Final - {student[2]}")
   # Find and display the student with the highest average grade
   highest_avg_student = find_highest_average(student_grades)
   print("\nStudent with the Highest Average Grade:")
   print(f"{highest_avg_student[0]} with an average grade of {calculate_average(highest_avg_student)}")
   # Sort and display the list of students based on average grades
   sorted_students = sort_students_by_average(student_grades)
   print("\nSorted Student Grades (Highest to Lowest Average):")
   for student in sorted_students:
      print(f"{student[0]}: Average - {calculate_average(student)}")
```

When I run it, it gives me the most random numbers and never the true average. This is the output.

```
Student #1 Joe
Student #2 Bill
Student #3 Sally
Student #4 Samantha
Student #5 Gilly
Student #1 Midterm Grade 97
Student #2 Midterm Grade 48
Student #3 Midterm Grade 95
Student #4 Midterm Grade 100
Student #5 Midterm Grade 89
Student #1 Endterm Grade 99
Student #2 Endterm Grade 98
Student #3 Endterm Grade 87
Student #4 Endterm Grade 80
Student #5 Endterm Grade 72
Original Student Grades:
Joe: Midterm - 97, Final - 99
Bill: Midterm - 48, Final - 98
Sally: Midterm - 95, Final - 87
Samantha: Midterm - 100, Final - 80
Gilly: Midterm - 89, Final - 72

Student with the Highest Average Grade:
Samantha with an average grade of 5040.0

Sorted Student Grades (Highest to Lowest Average):
Samantha: Average - 5040.0
Joe: Average - 4899.5
Sally: Average - 4793.5
Gilly: Average - 4486.0
Bill: Average - 2449.0
```

Why is it doing the math wrong?

Comment: You need to convert to int each grade, not concatenate 2 grades and only then convert. e.g. you find the half of 9799

Comment: Any time you are tempted to name variables with numeric suffixes such as thing1, thing2, ... you should be using a list.

Comment: Why don't you convert all your grades to integer at the time you take input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the values into ints before you add them in the average calculation. e.g. You did `int("97" + "99") / 2` which is equivalent to `9799 / 2`

Try this:

```
def calculate_average(grades):
   return (int(grades[1]) + int(grades[2])) / 2
```

Or probably an easier method is to convert them to ints as soon as you parse the input:

```
MidTermGrade1 = int(input("Student #1 Midterm Grade"))
```

Comment: Thank You! I changed my code to look like this and now it works. Thanks a lot! In case you couldn't tell, I am new to python and don't have a whole lot of experience with some of these problems, so I appreciate the response.

Comment: @BillyJoel that's no problem. We're here to help!

Answer (score 1):

Your calculate_average function is wrong :
First you have to cast both grades to int, then to add them and finally to divide the result by 2.

You can do it like this :

```
def calculate_average(grades):
   return (int(grades[1]) + int(grades[2])) / 2
```